# Printing only words from a list that contain characters from another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a small problem for fun, sent to me by a friend. The problem requires me to populate an array with common words from a text file, and then print all the words from this list containing certain characters provided by the user. I am able to populate my array no problem, but it seems the part of the code that actually compares the two lists is not working. Below is the function I've written to compare the 2 lists.

```py
#Function that prompts user for the set of letters to match and then compares that list of letters to each word in our wordList.
def getLetters():
    #Prompt user for list of letters and convert that string into a list of characters
    string = input("Enter your target letters: ")
    letterList = list(string)
    #For each word in the wordList, loop through each character in the word and check to see if the character is in our letter list, if it is increase matchCount by 1.
    for word in wordList:
        matchCount = 0
        for char in word:
            if char in letterList:
                matchCount+=1
            #If matchCount is equal to the length of the word, all of the characters in the word are present in our letter list and the word should be added to our matchList.
            if matchCount == len(word):
                matchList.append(word)
    print(matchList)
```

The code runs just fine, I don't get any error output, but once the user enters their list of letters, nothing happens. To test I've tried a few inputs matching up with words I know are in my wordList (e.g. added, axe, tree, etc). But nothing ever prints after I enter my letter string.

This is how I populate my wordList:

```py
def readWords(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            #Load entire file as string, split string into word list using whitespace as delimiter
            s = file.read()
            wordList = s.split(" ")
            getLetters()
    #Error handling for invalid filename. Just prompts the user for filename again. Should change to use ospath.exists. But does the job for now
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist, check directory and try again. Dictionary file must be in program directory because I am bad and am not using ospath.")
        getFile()
```

Edit: Changed the function to reset matchCount to 0 before it starts looping characters, still no output.

Comment: Here's a tip: There is a clever, much simpler solution that uses Python sets. This problem is a nice demonstration of how cool Python can be some times. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only needs a simple change:

Pass wordList as a parameter for `getLetters`. Also if you like you could make a change in order to know if all the letters of the word are in the letter list.

```
def getLetters(wordList):
    string = input("Enter your target letters: ")
    letterList = list(string)
    matchList = []
    for word in wordList:
        if all([letter in letterList for letter in word]):
            matchList.append(word)
    return matchList
```

And in `readWords`:

```
def readWords(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            s = file.read()
            wordList = s.split(" ")
            result = getLetters(wordList)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("...")
    else:
        # No exceptions.
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: add a global declaration to modify your list from inside a function:

```
wordList = [] #['axe', 'tree', 'etc']
def readWords(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            s = file.read()
            global wordList  # must add to modify global list
            wordList = s.split(" ")
    except:
        pass
```

Here is a working example:

```
wordList = ['axe', 'tree', 'etc']


# Function that prompts user for the set of letters to match and then compares that list of letters to each word in our wordList.
def getLetters():
    # Prompt user for list of letters and convert that string into a list of characters
    string = input("Enter your target letters: ")
    letterList = list(string)
    # For each word in the wordList, loop through each character in the word and check to see if the character is in our letter list, if it is increase matchCount by 1.
    matchList = []
    for word in wordList:
        matchCount = 0
        for char in word:
            if char in letterList:
                matchCount += 1
            # If matchCount is equal to the length of the word, all of the characters in the word are present in our letter list and the word should be added to our matchList.
            if matchCount == len(word):
                matchList.append(word)
    print(matchList)

getLetters()
```

output:

```
Enter your target letters: xae
['axe']
```

Comment: Hmm. The only difference I'm seeing here is in your wordList. Currently mine is pulled from a text file containing common words separated by whitespace.

```python
def readWords(filename):
 try:
  with open(filename) as file:
   #Load entire file as string, split string into word list using whitespace as delimiter
   s = file.read()
   wordList = s.split(" ")
   getLetters()
```

Any reason this would break everything?

Comment: i think you should print your wordlist after loading values from your file to see if its loaded correctly or not

Comment: I have done this, it prints the entire list of 10 thousand words.

Comment: also you have to reset "matchCount = 0" before every match, check my answer, i added that line just before "for char in word:"

Comment: Yeah, I already edited my OP to reflect that change. It didn't change anything for me :(

Comment: Is it possible that because of how I populate my array, each entry isn't considered a word?

Comment: i think you created your list right by "wordList = s.split(" ")", you can try with text file with 3 words only as a test and run your script with printing wordlist, and post results

Comment: Sure, I just tried with a test document containing only 3 words, the same words contained in your text. No output. However if I print just the wordList, all 3 words are there. The issue is definitely with my matching code.

Comment: yes i've got it now, your "readWords(filename):" function missing global declaration i added to my answer

Comment: Modifying a global list from inside a function is terrible design. And why? If you want your function to populate a list, that's what `return` is for.